# index list out of range

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

The point of the following code is to take range of `a`, `b` and a list variable and compare the numbers between the range suggested to the list numbers.

If the number is on the list greater than `a` and lower than `b`, count it as one. And none, that count nothing.

```
def between(lst, a, b):
    i=len(lst)
    count = 0
    for n in range(a, b):
        if lst[n] > a and lst[n] < b:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = count + 0                   
    return count
    
# TESTS 

print("********************")
print("Starting the test:")
    
print("********************")
print("Counting over [1, 2, 3, 4] with a = 0, b = 5")
ans = between([1, 2, 3, 4], 0, 5)
if ans == 4:
    print("CORRECT: Very good, there are 4 elements between a = 0 and b = 5 in [1, 2, 3, 4]")
else:
    print("WRONG: There are 4 elements between a = 0 and b = 5 in [1, 2, 3, 4] but the code returned", ans)

print("********************")
print("Counting over [-5, 20, 13, 0] with a = 200, b = 300")
ans = between([-5, 20, 13, 0], 200, 300)
if ans == 0:
    print("CORRECT: Very good, there are no elements between a = 200 and b = 300 in [-5, 20, 13, 0]")
else:
    print("WRONG: There are no elements between a = 200 and b = 300 in [-5, 20, 13, 0] but the code returned", ans)
    
print("********************")
print("Counting over [-5, 20, 13, 0] with a = -10, b = 5")
ans = between([-5, 20, 13, 0], -10, 5)
if ans == 2:
    print("CORRECT: Very good, there are 2 elements between a = -10 and b = 5 in [-5, 20, 13, 0]")
else:
    print("WRONG: There are 2 elements between a = -10 and b = 5 in [-5, 20, 13, 0] but the code returned", ans)

print("********************")    
print("Tests concluded, add more tests of your own below!")
print("********************")
```

Comment: please include the "python" tag in your quesiton.

Comment: And your question is...? Why you get "list index out of range"? Why *shouldn't* you get it?

Comment: Look at the values taken by `n` and you'll quickly see your answer.

Comment: P.S. the algorithm you appear to be building is going to be very slow.  Instead of trying to fix this code you might want to consider a different way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your `between` function. You could have found it using a debugger (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) for example).

A correct version :

```py
def between(lst, a, b):
    count = 0
    for elem in lst:
        if a <= elem <= b:
            count = count + 1                 
    return count
```

A shorter (and faster) version :

```py
def between(lst, a, b):
    return sum(1 for elem in lst if a <= elem <= b)
```